# Bezier Curve Classification

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, bezier-curve

Given four cubic Bezier control points in the plane, I would like to render a curve.

From this article

http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch25.html

the following values a1, a2, and a3 are said to be:

> a1 = b0 · (b3 x b2)
>
> a2 = b1 · (b0 x b3)
>
> a3 = b2 · (b1 x b1)

The cross product of two non-zero, non-collinear vectors in a plane will always result in a vector orthogonal to the plane. The dot product of two vectors who are orthogonal to each other will always be 0. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article uses a 3D representation $(x,y,1)$ for a 2D point $(x,y)$. 
Note that the last coordinate is set to 1. You may then calculate the above constants (in fact each constant is just a determinant of a 3 by 3 matrix with one line (or row) being ones. Technically speeking the author uses a projective representation of the affine plane.

Comment: Interesting... Won't (b1 x b1) still always be (0, 0, 0) though?

Comment: Good observation. Indeed, so there must be an error in the article. In view of the symmetry of the indices (cyclic permutation), I guess it should read  $a3=b2\cdot(b1\times b0)$ for the last.